# Reading JSON using a JsonTextReader throws an error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to read JSON data stored as string from a database, and I need to convert the data in different ways.  I have seen an error is thrown from a `JsonTextReader` internally by JSON.NET. I have tried to reproduce the error by directly using the following code.  What is wrong with this code?

```
var rs = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader("{'1':'2'}"));
rs.ReadAsString();
```

It throws an error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because you are using the `JsonTextReader` incorrectly.

The [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class treats a JSON string as a series of "tokens" which are read one at a time.  The possible tokens are defined by the [`JsonToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) enumeration, including `StartObject`, `StartArray`, `PropertyName`, `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Null`, `EndObject`, and `EndArray` to name a few.

When you call `ReadAsString`, that advances the reader to the next token and attempts to interpret that token as a string.  In your JSON, the first token is not a string; it is `StartObject` (corresponding to the left curly brace `{`).  `ReadAsString` is not expecting this, so it throws an error.

The `ReadAs...` methods are really only useful in cases where you already know in advance that the next token to be encountered by the reader will be a particular type (e.g. string).  If you don't know the JSON structure in advance and want to use a `JsonTextReader` to scan through it, you can do it by calling the `Read` method in a loop until it returns false.  Each `Read` call advances the reader to the next token and sets the `TokenType` and `Value` properties.  You can then check the `TokenType` to determine how to handle the `Value`.

Here is a simple example which uses a `JsonTextReader` to loop through through the JSON and dump out the `TokenType` and `Value` at each step.  This should give you a good idea of how the reader sees your JSON:

```
JsonTextReader rs = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader("{'1':'2'}"));

Console.WriteLine("TokenType     Value");
Console.WriteLine("------------  ------");
while (rs.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-12}  {1}", 
        rs.TokenType.ToString(),
        rs.Value != null ? rs.Value.ToString() : "(null)"));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxWd1X

Here is the output:

```
TokenType     Value
------------  ------
StartObject   (null)
PropertyName  1
String        2
EndObject     (null)
```

---

Keep in mind the `JsonTextReader` is a pretty low-level API for parsing JSON, and can become unwieldy to use for all but the the simplest JSON structures.  If your JSON has a well-known structure, it may be easier to define a matching class (or set of classes) and deserialize into that using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm).  For example:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string One { get; set; }
}

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{'1':'2'}");

Console.WriteLine(root.One);   // 2
```

Alternatively, if your JSON structure is dynamic or not well known, you can use the [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API (JObjects) instead.  For example:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{'1':'2'}");
foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);   // 1: 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have figured it out. My intention was to read the complete JSON  as string and Deserialize it. I have to implement a Generic `Task<T> Get<T>(key)` method for an interface where the actual implementation need to fetch data from a data store which stores data as JSON, mostly it is serialized objects as JSON format but sometimes I have to return read string as well, where T is String, I have used `JSONConvert.DeserilaizeObject<T>(string)` for this , That is where I get this error.